# Tengo un error constante en Debian cuando quiero actualizar mi sistema

Tags: linux, debian

$ apt-get update

```
  Obj:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
  Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease   
  Obj:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Obj:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release     
  Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
  W: http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease: The key(s) 
  in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not 
   readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
   W: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease: The 
   key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not 
  readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
  W: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/Release.gpg: The key(s) in 
   the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable 
    by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
```

$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Release:    9.1
Codename:   stretch
```

cat  /etc/apt/sources.list

```
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch/updates main contrib
# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
```

¿Que puedo hacer ? parece como si hubiera problemas con los permisos de ejecución.

Comment: Woooow!! En mi caso, me funciono a la perfeccion la solucion de Neftali Yagua, llevaba un mes con problemas de no poder actualizar mi debian, con esto se me resolvio todo problema con las llaves. Gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Es un problema de permisos. 
Necesitas ejecutar:

```
unlink /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
```

luego ejecuta synaptic
busca un paquete llama debian-archive-keyring selecciona la opción reinstalar.
Luego de reinstalarla cierra synaptic y ejecuta

```
apt update
```

o también puedes recargar desde synaptic pero te recomiendo que lo hagas desde consola para que puedas ver si te arroja alguna información adicional.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías probara hacer el update con el super usuario de esta manera:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a editar el archivo **/etc/apt/source-list** con la siguiente información y luego hacer "**sudo apt-get -y update**"

```
# stretch-oficiales
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

# stretch-actualizaciones-seguridad
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

# debian-multimedia
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

Si lo anterior no te funciona en [esta](https://www.comoinstalarlinux.com/como-solucionar-problemas-al-instalar-o-actualizar-paquetes-en-ubuntu-o-linux-mint/) página hay varios ejemplos más sobre como solucionarlo que creo que te podrían ayudar.